# FFmpeg/DASH: duration or timestamp out of range for mov/mp4 format

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, shaka

I'm trying to convert a `aac` stream to dash. The issue is that I get a lot of errors as below(though it seems to segment it into multiple files but I get errors on the player too). The question is why do I get these errors and how can I fix it? If I simply convert "copy" it into  to a single mp4 file it works without error.

```
    ffmpeg -i  "a.mkv" -y -map  0:1 -c:0 copy -min_seg_duration 1000000 
-use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -init_seg_name init.mp4s 
-media_seg_name  "\$Number\$.mp4s" -adaptation_sets "id=1,streams=0"
-remove_at_exit 0  -f dash -dash 1 
"out/stream.mpd" -loglevel error
```

Output

```
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 40475608 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 40764376 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 40860664 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 41149432 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 41390056 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x7fbb70819600] Application provided duration: -32 / timestamp: 41823208 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
```

Copy to a single MP4 works just fine
 ffmpeg -i  "a.mkv" -y -map  0:1 -c:0 copy  -f mp4 -dash 1 "out/out.mp4" -loglevel error

Probe

```
ffprobe a.mkv
ffprobe version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'a.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.1 + libmatroska v1.4.2
    creation_time   : 2017-03-11T02:56:50.000000Z
  Duration: 02:12:52.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 740 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 520.270000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 520.270000, end 1135.718000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:08:40.270
    Chapter #0:2: start 1135.718000, end 1703.660000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:18:55.718
    Chapter #0:3: start 1703.660000, end 2314.187000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:28:23.660
    Chapter #0:4: start 2314.187000, end 2888.594000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:38:34.187
    Chapter #0:5: start 2888.594000, end 3499.246000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:48:08.594
    Chapter #0:6: start 3499.246000, end 4154.692000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:58:19.246
    Chapter #0:7: start 4154.692000, end 4646.392000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:09:14.692
    Chapter #0:8: start 4646.392000, end 5373.660000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:17:26.392
    Chapter #0:9: start 5373.660000, end 5882.085000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:29:33.660
    Chapter #0:10: start 5882.085000, end 6627.871000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:38:02.085
    Chapter #0:11: start 6627.871000, end 7144.471000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:50:27.871
    Chapter #0:12: start 7144.471000, end 7451.944000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:59:04.471
    Chapter #0:13: start 7451.944000, end 7972.394000
    Metadata:
      title           : 02:04:11.944
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, progressive), 720x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : X264
      BPS             : 623765
      BPS-eng         : 623765
      DURATION        : 02:12:52.311000000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:12:52.311000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 191144
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 191144
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 621606403
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 621606403
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.3.0 ('Over the Horizon') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.3.0 ('Over the Horizon') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-03-11 02:56:50
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-03-11 02:56:50
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 114797
      BPS-eng         : 114797
      DURATION        : 02:12:52.394000000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:12:52.394000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 373706
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 373706
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 114401387
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 114401387
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.3.0 ('Over the Horizon') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.3.0 ('Over the Horizon') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-03-11 02:56:50
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-03-11 02:56:50
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

Shaka debug

```
Assertion failed: This should be an update of the last segment in a period
shaka.media.SegmentIndex.merge @ segment_index.js:153
shaka.dash.SegmentTemplate.createStream @ segment_template.js:82
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseRepresentation_ @ dash_parser.js:1080
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseAdaptationSet_ @ dash_parser.js:978
shaka.dash.DashParser.parsePeriod_ @ dash_parser.js:722
shaka.dash.DashParser.parsePeriods_ @ dash_parser.js:626
shaka.dash.DashParser.processManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:520
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:431
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:430
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:397
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.requestManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:390
shaka.dash.DashParser.onUpdate_ @ dash_parser.js:1161
setTimeout (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.setUpdateTimer_ @ dash_parser.js:1209
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:331
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.start @ dash_parser.js:329
(anonymous) @ player.js:555
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.util.CancelableChain.then @ cancelable_chain.js:72
shaka.Player.load @ player.js:499
initPlayer @ ?x=149&y=88&q=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fmeta%2F%3FbucketID%3D%2FVolumes%2FTV%2FFa%26channelID%3D%2FVolumes%2FTV%26containerID%3D%2FUsers%2F%2Fbrev%%2FL1ZvbHVtZXMvVFYvRmFudGFzdGljLkJlYXN0cy5hbmQuV2hlcmUudG8uRmluZC5UaGVtLjIwMTYuQkRSaXAueDI2NC1TUEFSS1MvYS5ta3Y%2F97M4TS6IqnQ.mpd:392
463segment_index.js:145 Refusing to rewrite original references on update!
shaka.media.SegmentIndex.merge @ segment_index.js:145
shaka.dash.SegmentTemplate.createStream @ segment_template.js:82
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseRepresentation_ @ dash_parser.js:1080
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseAdaptationSet_ @ dash_parser.js:978
shaka.dash.DashParser.parsePeriod_ @ dash_parser.js:722
shaka.dash.DashParser.parsePeriods_ @ dash_parser.js:626
shaka.dash.DashParser.processManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:520
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:431
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.parseManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:430
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:397
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.requestManifest_ @ dash_parser.js:390
shaka.dash.DashParser.onUpdate_ @ dash_parser.js:1161
setTimeout (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.setUpdateTimer_ @ dash_parser.js:1209
(anonymous) @ dash_parser.js:331
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.dash.DashParser.start @ dash_parser.js:329
(anonymous) @ player.js:555
Promise resolved (async)
shaka.util.CancelableChain.then @ cancelable_chain.js:72
shaka.Player.load @ player.js:499
initPlayer @ ?x=149&y=88&q=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fmeta%2F%3FbucketID%3D%2FVolumes%2FTV%2FFa%26channelID%3D%2FVolumes%2FTV%26containerID%3D%2FUsers%2F%2Fbrev%%2FL1ZvbHVtZXMvVFYvRmFudGFzdGljLkJlYXN0cy5hbmQuV2hlcmUudG8uRmluZC5UaGVtLjIwMTYuQkRSaXAueDI2NC1TUEFSS1MvYS5ta3Y%2F97M4TS6IqnQ.mpd:392
```

Comment: Sample files please.

Answer (score 0):

Captain Scheck pointed me to this question :)

I didn't investigate it in much detail but from the first look I would assume that the problem with your `ffmpeg` command is that you are telling `ffmpeg` to create dash media segments with the minimum segment length of 1 second but at the same time you are copying the encoded bitstream (which might not have random access points at the specified granularity) I'm more of a video guy (here I assume that for audio you also have RAPs etc.)

Here is what I would do:

Option 1, if you only need a single Representation:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -remove_at_exit 0 -seg_duration 1 -f dash audio.mpd
```

Option 2, if you need multiple bitrates here is an example with two Representations:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a:0 128k -b:a:1 64k -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -remove_at_exit 0 -seg_duration 1 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0,1" -f dash audio.mpd
```

I quickly tested those commands with [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) using the content from youtube:

```
youtube-dl -f 137+140 https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=QPC4Kyx-AVw -o in.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy a.mkv
```

Which has an `h.264` video stream `#0:0` and an `aac` audio stream `#0:1`